# Best library java to write dxf file

Tags: java, cad

I am looking for the best library to write a dxf file in java
Before trying to convert png image to dxf but I can't, so now I want to write the image directly
My need is a library that can draw lines and rotate them at an angle.

Answer (score 1):

You could try jdxf: https://jsevy.com/wordpress/index.php/java-and-android/jdxf-java-dxf-library/
You use standard AWT Graphics drawing commands on an instance of the DXFGraphics subclass just as you do for regular Graphics drawing. DXFGraphics generates a DXF file corresponding to the drawing operations. There's example code at the link above.